# IBM MQ - channel last used

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm new to mq and using mq explorer is there a way to find when was mq channel was last used? I have checked the channel status and also channel saved status.

Comment: Can you tell us the reason for wanting to know?

Comment: As I want to do a cleanup on channels thats have not been used for a while

Answer (score 0):

Search the queue manager log files for the channel name. It has channel start and stop entries.

Bear in mind that this will only work for qmgr-qmgr channel types. It will not work for SVRCONN types as they have no error log messages showing their start and stops.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to cover all channels of a queue manager is to use a product like [MQ Channel Connection Inspector](https://capitalware.com/mqcci_overview.html).

It produces a single CSV (Comma Separated Values) line each time an application connects and optionally when the application disconnect from the queue manager for SVRCONN channels.  It can also be used for queue manager to queue manager channels.